# Numbered citations in LaTeX

Tags: citing, natbib

How can I put citations in my text that are just numbers? At the moment, I am using the natbib package, which gives me citations in the form Weisstein [1]. I want citations that are just [1] and the number is displayed next to the corresponding reference. Which package can I use to do this?

The following is my preamble:

```
%This is the preamble of the document
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

and my citations look like this:

```
\begin{framed}
\noindent \textit{Sidenote:} A polygonal number \citet{Polygonal_number} is a number that can be expressed in dots and arranged in the shape of a polygon. The formula for the $n^{th}$ polygonal number, where the polygon has $s$ sides is: 
\[P(s,n)= \frac{n^2(s-2)- n(s-4)}{2}\]
\end{framed}
```

Answer (score 7):

To just obtain  the number, replace `\citet` with `\citep`.

The following MWE shows the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{example,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion A",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{example}

\citet{example}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a more in depth description of the differences, you can refer to section '2.3 Basic Citation Commands'  of the `natbib` manual (page 7), that contains several examples of code and the corresponding output.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! How can I number my references in the same way?

Comment: @user83024: To obtain numerical labels in the bibliography as well, you might want to use a numerical `bibliographystyle` as shown in my answer.

Comment: Is it supposed to make all the text italic and push it onto one line so it runs off the page?

Comment: No, it is definitely not supposed to. Unfortunately, I can not reproduce the error you describe with the information you already provided. Additional question: Why do you load `apacite` if you want to use a numerical citation and bibliography style?

Comment: I forgot to remove it.